# Excel 2010 moving data from 1 row to another if 1 cell is duplicate

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with various columns. Column 1 is a telephone number, another is a text field. However the telephone number can be repeated but the information in other field is unique.

For example

```
Column 1    Column 2  
11111111    A  
11111111    B  
11111111    777  
22222222    B  
22222222    C
```

Would like output to be:

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3    Column 4  
11111111     A           B           777  
22222222     B           C
```

Any ideas?

Any help is much appreaciated

Comment: Can you reformat your post - I think the line breaks are missing for your table layout... Your `<PRE> Table example with line breaks</PRE>` for better layout.

Answer (score 0):

Spreadsheet layout:

`B2:B7`: Phone number
`C2:C7`: Text
`F1` and to the right: Helper row with incrementing entry numbers (1,2,...n) to keep formulae simpler.

`E3`: Unique phone number:
`{=INDEX($B$3:$B$7;MATCH(0;COUNTIF($E$2:E2;$B$3:$B$7);0))}`
Array formula: press Shift-Ctrl-Enter in formula window to insert, curled brackets are inserted by Excel, not by a user. 
The formula can be copied down.

`F3`: Entries for the respective phone number:
`{=OFFSET($B$2;SMALL(IF($E3=$B$3:$B$7;ROW($B$3:$B$7)-ROW($B$2);"");F$1);1)}`
One more array formula, copied down and to the right

No error handling included: it's possible, but the length of formulae will double.

Example spreadsheet: http://www.bumpclub.ee/~jyri_r/Excel/Entries%20moved_to_one_row_for_duplicates.xls